# Azure AD B2C Local Account Password stops working after a few hours

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have created custom policies for social and local accounts based on the example from the [Active Directory B2C custom policy starter pack for social and local accounts](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts). I have enabled the login with Microsoft and Google and tested that both work, I have also enabled logging in with a local account.

The problem I am seeing is the local account.  I can create one and the password works fine for a few hours (not sure exactly how long), then starts giving a generic "Invalid username or password." error.  When I type in the wrong password for the same user I get a different message "Your password is incorrect" (this corresponds to a relevant log entry).

I have enabled application insights and can only find the following exceptions.

Any help on how to clear up these 2 errors would be great.

`""Statebag"": {
    ""Complex-CLMS"": {},
    ""ValidationRequest"": {
      ""ContentType"": ""Unspecified"",
      ""Created"": ""2017-10-04T19:17:49.2510644Z"",
      ""Key"": ""ValidationRequest"",
      ""Persistent"": true,
      ""Value"": ""client_id=307&resource=cf87&username=user%domain.com&password=fakep@ss!123&grant_type=password&scope=openid&nca=1;1;login-NonInteractive;False""
    },
    ""ValidationResponse"": {
      ""ContentType"": ""Json"",
      ""Created"": ""2017-10-04T19:17:49.2510644Z"",
      ""Key"": ""ValidationResponse"",
      ""Persistent"": true,
      ""Value"": ""{\""error\"":\""invalid_grant\"",\""error_description\"":\""AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '307' named 'IdentityExperienceFramework'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\\r\\nTrace ID: 7c4\\r\\nCorrelation ID: 3cc\\r\\nTimestamp: 2017-10-04 19:17:49Z\"",\""error_codes\"":[65001],\""timestamp\"":\""2017-10-04 19:17:49Z\"",\""trace_id\"":\""7c4\"",\""correlation_id\"":\""3cc\""};1;login-NonInteractive;False""
    },
    ""ComplexItems"": ""_MachineEventQ, REPRM, TCTX, M_EXCP""
  }`

Here is the 2nd exception

`""Key"": ""Exception"",
            ""Value"": {
              ""Kind"": ""Handled"",
              ""HResult"": ""80131500"",
              ""Message"": ""The technical Profile with id \""AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail\"" in Policy id \""B2C_1A_signup_signin of Tenant id \""xxx.onmicrosoft.com\"" requires that an error be raised if a claims principal record already exists for storing claims. A claims principal of type \""User\"" with identifier claim type id \""signInNames.emailAddress\"" does already exist."",
              ""Data"": {
                ""IsPolicySpecificError"": true,
                ""TenantId"": ""xxx.onmicrosoft.com"",
                ""PolicyId"": ""B2C_1A_signup_signin"",
                ""TechnicalProfile.Id"": ""AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail"",
                ""ClaimsPrincipal.IdentifierClaim.ClaimTypeId"": ""signInNames.emailAddress"",
                ""ClaimsPrincipal.PrincipalType"": ""User"",
                ""CreateClaimsPrincipalIfItDoesNotExist"": ""True"",
                ""RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists"": ""True"",
                ""RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist"": ""False""
              }
            }`

Here is the content of the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file.  The only difference between it and the example is that I am using 2 providers instead of 1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" 
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="xxx.onmicrosoft.com" 
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>xxx.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>

  </BuildingBlocks>

  <ClaimsProviders>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">307</Item>
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">cf8</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="307" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="cf8" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
        <Domain>Employee SignIn with Azure AD</Domain>
        <DisplayName>Employee Login</DisplayName>
        <TechnicalProfiles>
            <TechnicalProfile Id="AzureADProfile">
                <DisplayName>Employee Login</DisplayName>
                <Description>Login with your GP account</Description>
                <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
                <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.windows.net/yyy.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
                    <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/7de/</Item>
                    <Item Key="client_id">f19</Item>
                    <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">f19</Item>
                    <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
                    <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <CryptographicKeys>
                    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_AzureADAppSecret"/>
                </CryptographicKeys>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="contosoAuthentication" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="AzureADContoso" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
                </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
            </TechnicalProfile>
        </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <Domain>google.com</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Google</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Google-OAUTH">
            <DisplayName>Employee Login</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
            <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ProviderName">google</Item>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth</Item>
            <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">email</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id">zzz.apps.googleusercontent.com</Item>
            </Metadata>
            <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_GoogleSecret" />
            </CryptographicKeys>
            <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="google.com" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
            </OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
            <ErrorHandlers>
            <ErrorHandler>
                <ErrorResponseFormat>json</ErrorResponseFormat>
                <ResponseMatch>$[?(@@.error == 'invalid_grant')]</ResponseMatch>
                <Action>Reauthenticate</Action>
                <!--In case of authorization code used error, we don't want the user to select his account again.-->
                <!--AdditionalRequestParameters Key="prompt">select_account</AdditionalRequestParameters-->
            </ErrorHandler>
            </ErrorHandlers>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

  </ClaimsProviders>



  <UserJourneys>
      <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInUsingAzureAD">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>            
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AzureADExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>

        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AzureADExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AzureADProfile" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId). 
          This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
          using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
             from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
             (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
    </UserJourneys>

</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: Have you truncated the client id & audience in the question, or are those the real values? (i.e. 307 and cf8)

Comment: I have truncated, consistently I believe...

Answer (score 1):

Since the actual error could be due to a combination of policy and application configuration in the directory, I'll explain why these applications are required to be setup this way, and what could potentially be the issue. I am hoping that even if my guess on the root cause is wrong, this explanation will allow you to debug the issue further.

Think of an application that needs to validate a password for a user. Since the application does not have access to the password, one of the ways is to send an authentication request to login.microsoftonline.com with user's ID and password, and see if a token is successfully issued.

However, when this application sends a request, it must specify some resource, and must also have permissions on user's behalf to access that resource. A common workaround is for the administrator to grant permissions (i.e. consent) on behalf of all users.

IEF uses the same model. Your policy has two applications, one acts as client that gets a token on user's behalf to the resource. If you followed instructions on the "[Custom Policies Get Started Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom)", then ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework is the client, and IdentityExperienceFramework is the resource. As per those instructions, only ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework can get a token to IdentityExperienceFramework on user's behalf and not vice versa.

Based on the error message in your logs, it *seems* that you may have reversed the IDs for the client and the resource:

> The user or administrator has not consented to use the application
>   with ID '307' named '**IdentityExperienceFramework**'

That is, the client called `IdentityExperienceFramework` does not have access to get a token.

So you will need to check in the Azure AD portal which application has access to which application and update client ID and resource ID.

The second exception may really be by design, it's just telling you that the user that is being created in the directory already exists. This typically happens in sign up and, based on your policy settings, it will typically render an error message to the user indicating that the account already exists and they should instead sign in.

Answer (score 0):

This error

```
The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '307' named 'IdentityExperienceFramework'.
```

have you pressed the Grant Permissions button on this app within the AZURE AD blade within Azure

2nd exception

It looks like you are trying to write the user principal again and in your metadata it has the RaiseErrorIfUserPrincipalExists set to rue

The strange thing is neither really helps me to understand why your password doesnt work after a few hours

Best bet is to copy the policy here and we can attempt to tell you why your trying a write instead of a read

Comment: the only real difference between my policy and the sample is in the trustframeworextensions.xml file, I have copied it into the question.

Comment: I swear I pressed that grant button before, but when I pressed it the password error went away, but the 2nd exception still exists.

Comment: Can you add the technical profile AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail , its in the base , although the sample online has this line   <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item> changing true to false will prevent the error being logged

Comment: Its set to true, if I make that false, how can I tell if that event wasn't triggering some other behavior.